# How do I make an custom drawn resizable container?

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, custom-controls, ownerdrawn

I have a WinForms gui application which has a number of areas to it which I'd like to custom-draw some graphics. These areas would contain controls and be resizeable. I'm currently thinking of inheriting from a `TableLayoutPanel` and handling onpaint messages.

Does this sound like a good way to go or are there other/better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Windows Forms control has a Paint event, you don't have to derive your own class.  But sure, you can, it helps partitioning the code.  Just pick a base class that already provides most of what you need.  Set the DoubleBuffered property to true in the constructor and override OnPaint.